# How to download Ubuntu One folders to my computer?

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one

I am running 11.10 on a Dell D600 laptop and I uploaded files to my Ubuntu One account from my desktop.

I would like to download them to the laptop. I can access my cloud from the laptop but I don't know how to download the files.

Answer (score 3):

Can you connect to Ubuntu One (on your laptop) from the Messaging menu?

*(it's the icon in the upper-right that looks like an envelope)*

Once you are connected, click on the "Cloud Folders" tab to get a list of your currently sync'd folders.  I know for 11.04, it syncs everything with the "Ubuntu One" directory (on your home directory).

```
~/Ubuntu One
```

If you try that and you're still having issues, [here is a link for Ubuntu One help](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-ubuntu-one/) that is specific to 11.04 and 11.10.